# reactjs use memo: whats the need to pass functions for memo

Tags: reactjs

I saw this code in reactjs

```
function AppRouter(){
  const [value, setValue] = useState("hello")
  const providerValue = useMemo(() => ({value, setValue}), [value, setValue])
.......
}
```

what the point in keeping in memory the setValue function.

I can understand `value` can change.

Comment: Are you asking "what's the point" for code you wrote? Either way, it looks like the intention of this code is to prevent re-creating the `provderValue` object on every render. If you did `const providerValue = { value, setValue };` then it would create an entirely new object every render, which I'm guessing would affect some further downstream code.